# Manually fade in a newly added subview?

Tags: iphone, core-animation, subview, ios

I want a view to fade in when being added to the stack via

`[self.view addSubview:someSecondaryViewController.view];`

How do I animate this call so that the view fades in (and out)?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Set the alpha to zero before animating, then animate the alpha to one.

```
[fadingView setAlpha:0.0];
[containerView addSubview:fadingView];
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[fadingView setAlpha:1.0];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Before removing the view, just animate the alpha back to zero.

BTW, the view hierarchy is more of a tree than a stack.

Edit:

If you have no other cleanup after the animation ends when fading out the view, then use:

```
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:fadingView];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```

If you are already setting a didStopSelector then call removeFromSuperview there.

Comment: What happens when my fade ends at 0.0? It seems to be removing my subview. I want this to happen, but should I worry about memory management? If I explicitly add code to remove the subview, the animation doesn't show.

Comment: Use the `+setAnimationDidStopSelector` method to remove the `fadingView` from the superview.

Answer (score 21):

You could also use blocks to remove a view from its super view after it has finished the fade out animation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                 animations:^{viewOut.alpha = 0.0;}
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){[viewOut removeFromSuperview];}];
```

Answer (score 1):

And in Swift …

[In](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:animations:)

```swift
someSecondaryViewController.view.alpha = 0.0
self.view.addSubview(someSecondaryViewController.view)
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: { self.someSecondaryViewController.view.alpha = 1.0 })
```

[Out](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIView/animateWithDuration:animations:completion:)

```swift
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: { self.someSecondaryViewController.view.alpha = 0.0 }) { (done: Bool) in
    self.someSecondaryViewController.view.removeFromSuperview()
}
```